# is there a hashing function that satisfies the following

Tags: c++, algorithm, math, hash, cryptography

is there a hashing algorithm that satisfies the following?

`let "hash_funct" be a hashing function that takes two args, and returns a hash value. so all the following will be true`

`Hash1 = hash_funct(arg1, arg2) <=> hash_funct(Hash1, arg1) = hash_funct(Hash1, arg2) = Hash1;`

Can anyone point me to this Algorithm? or if it doesn't exist, can anyone collaborate with me to invent it?

more explanation:

imagine a set `S={A,B,C,D}`, and the Hashing function above.

if we can make: `Hash1 = hash_funct(A,B,C,D)`, then we can check if an element `X` is in the set by checking the hash result of `hash_funct(Hash1,X) == Hash1 ? belogns to the set : doesn't belong`

with this property we make checking the exisitance of an element in a set O(1) instead of O(NlogN)

Comment: `hash_funct(Hash1, arg1) = hash_funct(Hash1, arg2) = Hash1;` I don't understand the usefulness of this property. It seems that it just ignores the second parameter, and otherwise it is just identity.

Comment: You might want to exclude a constant function. :)

Comment: @geza- this is a very useful property. if you have a set of fixed and known elements, you can make a hash value out of all the elements "Hash1", to check if an element A is in the set you check `hash_funct(Hash1, A)` if it gives you the hash "Hash1" then this element is in the set otherwise it is not. with this hash function checking if an element is in a set becomes O(1).

Comment: See this https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Accumulator_(cryptography)

Comment: @kelalaka: bingo!

Comment: @organicoman Now they are highly popular with digital coins. see [this](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/30873/deletion-in-rsa-accumulator)

Comment: @organicoman: "otherwise it is not". If you didn't specify this, then you won't get this property. There will be a little chance, that it is not true, if you don't design a hash function to have this strong property. Check out https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bloom_filter, if you haven't already, maybe it can help.

Comment: @geza: thanks.. i already figure out a way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose Highest common factor(*Hcf*) will fit right here. Let a and b be two numbers with x as their highest common factor.

```
hcf(a,b) = x.
```

This means `a = x*m` and `b = x*n`. This clearly means that:

```
hcf(x,x*m) = hcf(x,x*n) = hcf(x*n,x*m) = x
```

Comment: very cleaver idea, but what if you apply this function for more than one element?

Answer (score 2):

What you are looking for is the [Accumulators](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Accumulator_(cryptography)). Currently, they are very popular with [digital coins @youtube](https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=rsa%20accumulator)

From Wikipedia;

> A cryptographic accumulator is a one-way membership function. It answers a query as to whether a potential candidate is a member of a set without revealing the individual members of the set.

For example this [paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/0905.1307v1.pdf);

> We show how to use the RSA one-way accumulator to realize an efficient and dynamic authenticated dictionary, where untrusted directories provide cryptographically verifiable answers
>   to membership queries on a set maintained by a trusted source

With a Straightforward Accumulator-Based Scheme;

- Query: When asking for a proof of membership.
- Verification: check the validity of the answer.
- Updates: Insertion and deletions

are available.